# Draw a line/border on a custom panel

Tags: c#, wpf, panel

I have made a custom panel, something similar to a WrapPanel but with columns (or like a Grid but the items are automatically positioned in the grid).

This is what it looks like:
[image: My custom panel]

I would like to have a property on my panel which makes a line between each column. Is it possible to draw on a custom panel?
The result I'm looking for is something like this (note the black line):
[image: Result wanted]
Edit: If I make the window wider the panel will automatically create more columns, so the separator lines have to be dynamic - that is, it may be zero, one, two, three or more separator lines.

This is the code for my panel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication26
{
    public class AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel : Panel
    {
        public double MinColumnWidth { get; set; }
        //public bool ShowColumnSeparator { get; set; }

        public AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel()
        {
            MinColumnWidth = 100;
        }

        protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
        {
            return DoLayout(availableSize, (uiElement, size, pos) => uiElement.Measure(size));
        }

        protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size finalSize)
        {
            return DoLayout(finalSize, (uiElement, size, pos) => uiElement.Arrange(pos));
        }

        private Size DoLayout(Size availableSize, Action<UIElement, Size, Rect> layoutAction)
        {
            // Calculate number of columns and column width
            int numberOfColumns = 0;
            double columnWidth = MinColumnWidth;
            if (double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Width))
            {
                numberOfColumns = InternalChildren.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                numberOfColumns = (int)Math.Max(Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / MinColumnWidth), 1);
                columnWidth = availableSize.Width / numberOfColumns;
            }

            // Init layout parameters
            Size measureSize = new Size(columnWidth, availableSize.Height);
            int currentColumn = 0;
            int currentRow = 0;
            double currentY = 0;
            double currentRowHeight = 0;
            // Place all items.
            foreach (UIElement item in InternalChildren)
            {
                var position = new Rect(currentColumn++ * columnWidth, currentY, columnWidth, item.DesiredSize.Height);
                // Execute action passing: item = The child item to layout | measureSize = The size allocated for the child item | position = The final position and height of the child item.
                layoutAction(item, measureSize, position);
                // Keep the highest item on the row (so that we know where to start the next row).
                currentRowHeight = Math.Max(currentRowHeight, item.DesiredSize.Height);
                if (currentColumn == numberOfColumns)
                {
                    // The item placed was in the last column. Increment/reset layout counters.
                    currentRow++;
                    currentColumn = 0;
                    currentY += currentRowHeight;
                    currentRowHeight = 0;
                }
            }
            // Return total size of the items/panel.
            return new Size(numberOfColumns * columnWidth, currentY + currentRowHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my WPF window hosting the panel:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication26.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication26"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <local:AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel MinColumnWidth="200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="One" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock Text="Two: " Background="Beige"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Three" Background="DarkKhaki"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Four" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Five" Background="Beige" Height="50"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Six" Background="DarkKhaki"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Seven" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Eight" Background="Beige"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Nine" Background="DarkKhaki"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Ten" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Eleven" Background="Beige"/>
    </local:AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Should be possible by setting the border thickness of text block to something like `BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"`

Comment: @ywm sorry if I wasn't clear about that I was looking for a solution where I don't have to modify the contents of the panel. I want the panel to draw the lines, no matter what I place in the panel.

Comment: In that case you could set the border thickness on the panel instead.

Comment: @ywm Thank you for you suggestion but I want a vertical line to appear between each column (as in the second image). Anyhow, I think I can get it done by drawing in the OnRender-method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could override the method OnRender in my panel. The OnRender-method gives me a DrawingContext which allows me to draw lines (and other shapes).

I did a quick and dirty test and with some modifications I think I can make it work.
Here is the quick-and-dirty code, if anyone needs to get an idea of how it works:

```
protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
{
    var pen = new System.Windows.Media.Pen(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        double x = (i + 1) * _columnWidth;
        dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, 0), new Point(x, 1000));
    }
    base.OnRender(dc);
}
```

I'll try to remember to post the complete code once I'm finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the code for my requested panel, if anyone else needs a panel like this:

**AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication26
{
    public class AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel : Panel
    {
        // The least acceptable width of the columns show in the panel. 
        public double MinColumnWidth { get; set; }
        // Spacing between columns.
        public double HorizontalColumnPadding { get; set; }
        // If a vertical line should be shown between the columns.
        public bool ShowColumnSeparator { get; set; }
        // The pen used to draw the column separator.
        public System.Windows.Media.Pen ColumnSeparatorPen { get; set; }

        private double _columnWidth = 0;
        private int _numberOfColumns = 0;

        public AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel()
        {
            MinColumnWidth = 100;
            ShowColumnSeparator = true;
            HorizontalColumnPadding = 2.5;
            ColumnSeparatorPen = new System.Windows.Media.Pen(SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush, 1);
        }

        protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
        {
            if (ShowColumnSeparator)
            {
                // Draw vertical lines as column separators.
                for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfColumns - 1; i++)
                {
                    double x = (i * HorizontalColumnPadding * 2) + (i + 1) * _columnWidth + HorizontalColumnPadding;
                    dc.DrawLine(ColumnSeparatorPen, new Point(x, 0), new Point(x, ActualHeight));
                }
            }
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }

        protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
        {
            return DoLayout(availableSize, (uiElement, size, pos) => uiElement.Measure(size));
        }

        protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size finalSize)
        {
            return DoLayout(finalSize, (uiElement, size, pos) => uiElement.Arrange(pos));
        }

        private Size DoLayout(Size availableSize, Action<UIElement, Size, Rect> layoutAction)
        {
            // Calculate number of columns and column width
            int numberOfColumns = 0;
            double columnWidth = MinColumnWidth;
            if (double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Width))
            {
                numberOfColumns = InternalChildren.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                numberOfColumns = (int)Math.Max(Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / MinColumnWidth), 1);
                // Give the columns equal space. Subtract any margin needed (MarginWidth is applied to both sides of the column, but not before the first column or after the last). The margin may cause the column to be smaller than MinColumnWidth.
                columnWidth = ((availableSize.Width - ((numberOfColumns - 1) * HorizontalColumnPadding * 2)) / numberOfColumns);
            }

            // Init layout parameters
            Size measureSize = new Size(columnWidth, availableSize.Height);
            int currentColumn = 0;
            int currentRow = 0;
            double currentY = 0;
            double currentRowHeight = 0;
            // Place all items.
            foreach (UIElement item in InternalChildren)
            {
                var position = new Rect((currentColumn * HorizontalColumnPadding * 2) + (currentColumn * columnWidth), currentY, columnWidth, item.DesiredSize.Height);
                currentColumn++;
                // Execute action passing: item = The child item to layout | measureSize = The size allocated for the child item | position = The final position and height of the child item.
                layoutAction(item, measureSize, position);
                // Keep the highest item on the row (so that we know where to start the next row).
                currentRowHeight = Math.Max(currentRowHeight, item.DesiredSize.Height);
                if (currentColumn == numberOfColumns)
                {
                    // The item placed was in the last column. Increment/reset layout counters.
                    currentRow++;
                    currentColumn = 0;
                    currentY += currentRowHeight;
                    currentRowHeight = 0;
                }
            }

            _columnWidth = columnWidth;
            _numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;

            // Return total size of the items/panel.
            return new Size(numberOfColumns * columnWidth + ((numberOfColumns - 1) * HorizontalColumnPadding * 2), currentY + currentRowHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication26.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication26"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <local:AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel MinColumnWidth="200" HorizontalColumnPadding="5" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="One" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock Text="Two: " Background="Beige"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Three" Background="DarkKhaki"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Four" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Five" Background="Beige" Height="50"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Six" Background="DarkKhaki"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Seven" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Eight" Background="Beige"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Nine" Background="DarkKhaki"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Ten" Background="AliceBlue"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Eleven" Background="Beige"/>
    </local:AutoSizingColumnsWrapPanel>
</Window>
```

This will render like this:
[image]

...and when the window is stretched:
[image]